# Defining $G$-module from representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

Consider a group $G$ and a representation $\rho=(\rho_{ij})$ of degree $d$ as well as a $d$-dimensional vector space $V$. In the book *Algebra* by P. M. Cohn he states that we can turn $V$ into a $G$-module by defining the action of $x\in G$ on a basis $v_1,...,v_d$ by
$$
x v_i=\sum_j \rho_{i j}(x) v_j \quad(x \in G)
$$
and generally putting
$$
x \left(\sum \alpha_i v_i\right)=\sum \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x) v_j.
$$
What I understand from this is that we define the action of $x$ on a linear combination of the basis vectors by
$$
x\left(\sum_i \alpha_i v_i\right)=\sum_i \alpha x v_i=\sum_i \alpha_i \sum_j \rho_{i j}(x) v_j=\sum_{i, j} \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x) v_j.
$$
(Correct?)

He leaves it to the reader to show that it is a $G$-module, so I need to show that the multiplication satisfies for any $x,y\in G$, $\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{w}\in V$ and $c,d$ in the field:

1. $x \boldsymbol{v} \in V$,
2. $x(c \boldsymbol{v}+d \boldsymbol{w})=c(x \boldsymbol{v})+d(x \boldsymbol{w})$
3. $(x y) \boldsymbol{v}=x(y\boldsymbol{v})$
4. $\epsilon\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{v}$

My intend:

1. The linear combination of the basis vectors $\sum \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x) v_j$ is in $V$ by definition of a vector space, so $x \boldsymbol{v} \in V$.
2. Let $\boldsymbol{v}=\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ and $\boldsymbol{w}=\sum_i \beta_i v_i$ be arbitrary vectors in $V$. Then
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   x(c \boldsymbol{v}+d \boldsymbol{w}) & =x\left(\sum_i\left(c \alpha_i+d \beta_i\right) v_i\right) \\
   & =\sum_i\left(c \alpha_i+d \beta_i\right) \rho_{i j}(x) v_j \\
   & =\sum_i\left(c \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x) v_j+d \beta_i \rho_{i j}(x) v_j\right) \\
   & =c \sum_i \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x) v_j+d \sum_i \beta_i \rho_{i j}(x) v_j \\
   & =c x \boldsymbol{v}+d x \boldsymbol{v}
   \end{aligned}
   $$
3. We have
   $$
   (x y)\left(\sum_i \alpha_i v_i\right)=\sum_{i, j} \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x y) v_j=\sum_{i, j, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(x) \rho_{k j}(y) v_j
   $$
   and
   $$
   x\left(y \sum_i \alpha_i v_i\right)=x \sum_{i, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(y) v_k=\sum_{i, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(y) x v_k=\sum_{i, j, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(y) \rho_{k j}(x) v_j
   $$
   but this doesn't appear to be the same - what am I doing wrong?
4. Since $\rho$ is a representation it sends the identity $\epsilon\in G$ to the identity matrix and hence
   $$
   \epsilon \boldsymbol{v}=\sum_i \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(\epsilon) v_j=\sum_i \alpha_i \delta_{i j} v_j=\boldsymbol{v}
   $$
   Can someone see if my proofs are correct, and let me know what I am missing/misunderstanding in part 3 (associativity).